# How can i clone/copy a tr (tr contains td with select and input tag ) without coping value/data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to clone/copy a `tr` (containing `td` with `select` and `input` tag) without coping value/data. I am using `clone().val("");` but its not working.

My code is
HTML-

```
<table class="table" id="new_transportation">
<tr>
    <th>Sequance No</th>
    <th>Travel By</th>
    <th>Kilometer</th>
    <th>Time</th>
</tr>
<tr class="trans_row">
    <td style="width: 12%;">
        <select class="form-control sequance_no">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control tranportion_type">
            {% for transportation in transportations %}
                <option value="{{transportation.pk}}">{{transportation.tra_name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" value="" style="width: 46%;" class="form-control kelometer numeric" name="kelometer" id="distance_in_km" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"> km
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" value="" style="width: 46%;" class="form-control time time_in_min numeric" name="time"> min
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="action">
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="GetNewRaw(this);">+</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

AND Jquery-

```
function GetNewRaw(element) {
var row = $(element).parents('tr')
var new_raw = $(row).clone()

$(new_raw).find('.action').html('')
$(new_raw).find('.action').html('<a class="btn btn-success" style="cursor: pointer;color:#F11111;"">-</a>')

new_raw.insertAfter(row);}
```

Its coping the `tr` with value. Please help me to get the `tr` without value.

Comment: I assume your `input` has the value not the `tr`?

Comment: jQuery's clone() has a lot of hidden work, try `tr.cloneNode(true)`, which should discard form values.

Comment: Its not working !!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting value on the cloned node? Select the inputs

```
new_raw.find(":input").val("");
```

Comment: Thanks #epascarello .Its working well..but I want to copy sequence no of selecet..how can i do that??

Comment: I have no idea what that means. If you do not want to change the select value than change the selector to not include the select. `...find(":input").not(". sequance_no").val("");`